# Automatic ScrollViewer scrolling to bottom and top on set time interval

Tags: c#, wpf

I am displaying an ObservableCollection inside a Scrollviewer which contains about 50 rows. If I display them all at once, the text is too small. To make them big enough to see clearly, some of the entries will be out of view and I will need to scroll.

What I would like to do is display the top 35 in the main view (scrolled to top), then every 20 seconds automatically scroll to bottom which will show the bottom 15 rows (including some at top that it has space for obviously), wait 10 secs and then scroll back to top. Repeat over and over indefinitely.

It doesn't have to use a scrollviewer if there is a better way.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place them in an ItemsControl and re-template it with a ScrollViewer:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="theItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="theScrollViewer">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then create an animation task back in your main window:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        theItemsControl.Loaded += (s, e) => Task.Run(Animate);
    }

    private async Task Animate()
    {
        var theScrollViewer = theItemsControl.Template.FindName("theScrollViewer", theItemsControl) as ScrollViewer;
        while (true)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => theScrollViewer.ScrollToTop());
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => theScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom());
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
    }
```

If you want smooth scrolling then it's a little bit more complicated, you'll need to create animations for the scroll offset, set their positions to the virtual height of your ScrollViewer and trigger them in your animation task.

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks! I don't need smooth scrolling so that is fine. I'll add that code and give it a test in the morning.

Comment: Working perfectly after some tests. I have marked this as the solution. Thanks again!